# Why does the camera shake with multiple objects?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to make a game like Agario. But I can't understand the logic for the camera, I came up with this idea - to make a empty object, and inside it I will have round 2d pictures. I will calculate the middle and put the camera there, the code works, but the camera is shaking very much.

```
public List<Transform> objectsList;
public float smoothTime = 0.3f;
private Vector3 velocity = Vector3.zero;

void LateUpdate()
{
    Vector3 center = GetCenterOfObjects(objectsList);
    Vector3 targetPosition = new Vector3(center.x, center.y, -10);
    transform.position = Vector3.SmoothDamp(transform.position, targetPosition, ref velocity, smoothTime);
}

Vector3 GetCenterOfObjects(List<Transform> objects)
{
    if (objects.Count == 0)
    {
        return Vector3.zero;
    }
    Vector3 sum = Vector3.zero;
    foreach (Transform obj in objects)
    {
        sum += obj.position;
    }

    Vector3 center = sum / objects.Count;

    return center;
}
```

Comment: What part of the code you posted controls the camera position?

Comment: 'transform.position = Vector3.SmoothDamp(transform.position, targetPosition, ref velocity, smoothTime);'

Comment: if the camera is moving a lot it suggests your middle is moving alot..  perhaps you are after a lerp?

Comment: I tried to use the lerp with a value of 0.5 and 1, but nothing worked

Comment: I can't figure out what exactly needs to be checked. During the movement of my subjects, the camera shakes very much

Comment: The camera is probably shaking because of "micro" movements of the object. Try inserting something like an offset before moving the camera.

Comment: for example? I don't quite understand